# mod_wsgi and mod_php running together - possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, mod-php

Is it possible to run apache with mod_wsgi and mod_php running together to serve python and php pages?

If so where can I find info on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can mix then. See recipes towards end of section:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Specfically, the AddHandler/mod_rewrite/WSGI script fixup method.

This will allow a PHP site pages to take precedence with any URLs for which no PHP or static resources falling through to Python WSGI application.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that a request can only be handled by one module or the other so you can't mix PHP and WSGI code.  That means that if you use `WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /some/where/app.wsgi`, http://example.com/myapp/foo.php will be processed by either mod_wsgi or mod_php, not both (most likely by mod_wsgi).  This also means that your WSGI application can't be `/`.

Theoretically, if you can get mod_php to work as an Apache Filter, your python app could output an appropriate PHP content-type header (`application/x-httpd-php`) and PHP code and mod_php would process it, but I'm not sure if this can actually be done.  I see a [lot of stuff](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/04/17/filters.html) about mod_perl working this way, but it seems that you'll probably need to compile PHP using the `apache2filter` SAPI instead of the default apache2handler, but searching for apache2filter turns up a lot of bug reports and other noise, but my Google-fu is too weak to find instructions on how to compile it, configure it or use it.

Otherwise, just set both up following their directions: [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide), [mod_php5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).  If your distribution provides packages for apache, mod_php and mod_wsgi, use them and skip the compiling steps unless you really need to.  If your distribution provides `a2enmod` it should do most of the setup for you (at least the module-loading portion) but you'll need to set `WSGIScriptAlias` yourself.